# Updating All Objects in an Array with $[] (all positional operator) returns error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The user model has an array of notifications, which each have a "read" property (true or false). I'm trying to update "read" on all of these to "true". Here's my code:

```
 db.User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.token._id },
        { $set: { "notifications.$[].read" : true } }
 )
```

And the error I get:

```
  "name": "MongoError",
  "message": "cannot use the part (notifications of notifications.$[].read) to traverse the element...
```

I'm using mongoose. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try with `{multi : true}`

Comment: @dan674 Could you show sample document from User collection ?

Comment: Your MongoDB version? Less that 3.6 of course. [Read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) as is clearly states. Must have MongoDB 3.6